# como fazer curl -X POST -d em PHP

Tags: php, api, libcurl

Estou fazendo um integração com uma api que traz imóveis

Na documentação, está assim:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=1234&client_secret=abcd&grant_type=client_credentials" \
https://www.linkapi.com.br/oauth/token
```

Porém não sei como fazer em PHP, fiz da maneira abaixo, mas retornou em branco(`{}bool(true)`):

```
$client_id="1234";
$client_secret="abcd";
$url ="https://www.linkapi.com.br/oauth/token";

$process = curl_init($url);
$data = json_encode(array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($process);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O dado está em `x-www-form-urlencoded`, e não em JSON.

```
-d "client_id=1234&client_secret=abcd&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Isto é um *urlencoded*, e não um JSON.

---

Para ter exatamente o mesmo efeito, teria que utilizar:

```
$data = http_build_query(['grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret]);

$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]); // O -d utiliza `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` por padrão.
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Para "salvar" a resposta no curl_exec (o $resp).
$resp = curl_exec($process);
```

A única diferença é a remoção do `json` e o uso do [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: perfeito, deu certinho, obrigado! só pra eu aprender o urlencoded é por causa do -X?

Comment: e outra coisa, ele printou na tela {"access_token":"q95b","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31535701,"scope":"basic_info building_list building_details feedback","created_at":1586782560} como pego o acess_token?

Comment: @LeandroTeraoka Isso é por causa do `-d`, e devido ao tipo de dado que está sendo enviado. É uma serie de fatores. Se estivesse como `-d '{"client_id": 1234, "client_secret": abc}'` seria um JSON, você reconhece que isso é JSON. Enquanto que um `client_id=1234&client_secret=abcd` é um urlencoded, se fosse utilizasse o `-F` seria um `multipart/form-data`. Mas, especificamente sobre o JSON, provavelmente também usaria o `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` para sobrescrever o `Content-Type`.

Comment: @LeandroTeraoka Você deve usar o `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` para que o `$resp` tenha o valor da resposta. Isso é, `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`, editei a resposta para incluir isto.

Comment: deu certinho, muito obrigado!