# Curl Json retornando caracteres estranhos, não sendo possível salvar no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, json, libcurl

Gostaría de uma ajuda e peço desculpas se já houver resposta para esta pergunta aqui.

Assim:

1. Se eu executar o comando abaixo via SSH::

```html
    curl -X POST \
  https://pos-api.XXXXXXX.com.br/oauth/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=scott&client_secret=tiger&grant_type=password&username=merchantOne&password=keepitsecret'
```

Me Retorna, CORRETAMENTE, algo como no exemplo abaixo:
{
"access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3599,
"scope": "trust read write"
}

2. PORÉM, quando organizo o código abaixo no PHP, tendo mesmo objetivo do comando que postei lá no início:

```html
$url = "https://pos-api.XXXXXXXXX.com.br/oauth/token";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{"client_id":'.$client_id.',"client_secret":'.$client_secret.', "grant_type":'.$grant_type.',"username":'.$username.',"password":'.$password.'}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$token_gerado = var_dump($resp);
```

Recebo como resposta algo como:

```html
string(112) "�d�K � F��c!��t-@�R>��h�ٸ�w87�Tه�&��5ƚYK���*�(��� �����o��C��wҧ��"����^l9n" Dados atualizados com suesso!
```

Além disso, gostaria de organizar o retorno que vier sem o erro e salvar no banco de dados:
{
"access_token": "ab04421d-10d4-462c-b370-6456lrk897564aa48",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3599,
"scope": "trust read write"
}

No caso, esses comandos correspondem à documentação disponível aqui:
https://developer.ifood.com.br/docs/primeiros-passos-com-ifood-api

Comment: Consegui resolver seguindo as dicas da seguinte questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445909/como-fazer-curl-x-post-d-em-php